# Windows Phone app: Binding data in a UserControl which is contained in a ListBox

Tags: data-binding, user-controls, listbox, windows-phone

I have an "AddressListBox" ListBox that contains "AddressDetails" UserControl items, as shown in the .xaml file extract below. The Addresses collection is defined as

ObservableCollection< Address > Addresses

and Street, Number, PostCode, City are properties of the Address class. The binding fails, when I use the "{Binding property}" syntax shown below. The binding succeeds, when I use the "dummy" strings in the commented-out code. I have also tried "{Binding Path=property}" syntax without success. Can you suggest what syntax I should use for binding the data in the user controls?

```
        <ListBox x:Name="AddressListBox"

                 DataContext="{StaticResource dataSettings}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Addresses, Mode=TwoWay}">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <!--
                    <usercontrols:AddressDetails AddressRoad="dummy" AddressNumber="dummy2" AddressPostCode="dummy3" AddressCity="dummy4">
                    </usercontrols:AddressDetails>
                    -->

                    <usercontrols:AddressDetails AddressRoad="{Binding Street}" AddressNumber="{Binding Number}" AddressPostCode="{Binding PostCode}" AddressCity="{Binding City}">
                    </usercontrols:AddressDetails>

                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the datacontext on the usercontrol to the item like this.

`<usercontrols:AddressDetails DataContext={Binding}
...
</usercontrols:AddressDetails>`

Now your other bindings should work correctly as they are relative to the item.